# "Pinch to Zoom" using AutoLayout

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming, autolayout, pinch

I have followed many "Pinch to Zoom" tutorials I found online, and have done reading on AutoLayout, but I can't get it to work in my project.

My whole project uses AutoLayout, so I don't want to turn it off. 
I am loading a huge UIImage (EG: 5000px on long edge) into a UIImageView, and i'd like to be able to pinch to zoom and move around the zoomed in image.

I've tried using UIImageView inside a UISrollView, but I couldn't get it to work properly. The closest I could get was some random "glitching" where the image moved erratically when pinched.

Has anybody got 'Pinch to Zoom' to work using Autolayout in iOS 6? I don't care if it uses UIScrollView or something else, I'd just love to get it to work.

Thanks,

Isaac

Comment: Any luck with this? I want to do the same, as well as rotation. One solution offered was to turn off autolayout for the view during the gesture, then turn it back on. Seems kludgy to me.